# export excel from extjs grid

Tags: servlets, extjs

I want to export extjs grid content to excel file. So what i have done already:
i send to the servlet json content of the grid through Ext.Ajax.request, like

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'ExportToExcel',
        method:'POST',
        jsonData: this.store.proxy.reader.rawData,
        scope : this,
        success : function(response,options) {
            this.onExportSuccess(response, options);
        },
        //method to call when the request is a failure
        failure: function(response, options){
            alert("FAILURE: " + response.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Then in servlet i get json in servlet do some stuff, e.g. create excel file, convert it to bytes array and try to put into response.
In Ext.Ajax.request in success method when i try to do something like this:

```
var blob = new Blob([response.responseText], { type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet});

var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = downloadUrl;
a.download = filename;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

it downloads excel file, but when i open it error occurs, saying format or extension is invalid.

WHY??
Whether it may depend on the encoding?
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ext comes with an excel exporter built in. You may want to try using that to see if you get the desired results

```
  grid.saveDocumentAs({
    type: 'excel',
    title: 'My Excel Title',
    fileName: 'MyExcelFileName.xml'
});
```

From the toolkit : [Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter.html#method-saveDocumentAs)